# UIKeyboardWillShow called twice on first keyboard use

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I'm having an odd issue. I register keyboard listeners like so in `viewDidLoad`:

```
func registerObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

This is a single view controller test app. These observers are not registered anywhere else in the app. I have also not navigated between view controllers. The `keyboardWillAppear` handler code looks something like this:

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
            return
    }
    guard let keyboardAnimationDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber else {
            return
    }
    guard let keyboardAnimationCurve = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber else {
            return
    }
   // Animation code
}
```

When `keyboardWillShow` is called it will scroll and animate the selected row to just above the keyboard.

When I first load the app and tap on a cell `keyboardWillShow` is called twice, that is `UIKeyboardWillShow` has been fired twice. This is causing issues with my animation as this is also now called twice. Upon inspecting the frame in the notification it appears the frame in the first notification is incorrect to make the animation work correctly but the second notification's frame works. This only happens the first time the keyboard it used. If I tap off a cell and invoke the keyboard again `keyboardWillShow` will only be called once. What am I doing wrong here? Why is it firing twice on the first load?

Comment: Same issue that I faced early, If you use "NotificationCenter.default.addObserver" in ViewDidLoad() then you have remove "NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver" while viewDidDisappear()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove notification center while dismiss the page.

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) 
 {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
 }
```

Comment: Why do I need this? My test app above uses a single view controller. I'm not navigating anywhere else.

Comment: Because if you load func in viewDidLoad It will add multiple add notification centre

Comment: Why does it add the notification multiple times? I'm debugging now and it seems to only add it once.

Comment: @Kex, Once "Notification center addObserver" added to the viewController you have to remove "Notification center" while disappear otherwise it will add notificationCenter each time viewcontroller load