# ios - Keyboard Notification called on parent and child View Both

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnotifications

I have a parent view controller which have `UITextViews` inside and i needed notifications on it soo i did add observer for self on **parentViewCon**.

I have a subview inside of **parentViewCon** which is itself **viewcontroller** but it is added on a small portion of **parentViewController**.

This **childViewCon** have its own `UITextFields` and i need to have its own keyboard notification observers.

Now problem is when i tap `UITextField` in **childViewCon** the notifications of parent are fired as well because i couldn't remove those observers due to work flow of app. Is there a work around or a way to solve this kind of dependency?

Comment: Same issue that I faced early, If you use "NotificationCenter.default.addObserver" in ViewDidLoad() then you have remove "NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver" while viewDidDisappear() in each viewcontroller

Comment: check my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970870/uikeyboardwillshow-called-twice-on-first-keyboard-use/42971207#42971207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this scenario by Engaging Child view Controller with parent **notifications** i check for the `UIControls` if they exist in child then i resolve their keyboard **notifications** inside parent.